# Filtering Results - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a filter that essentially sits on top of the index action.  The idea is that a user can check off a certain set of attributes (while leaving others unchecked for attributes they don't care about).  After submitting, the result should come back with all items that satisfy those attributes (while ignoring unchecked attributes).

I've seen bits an pieces of code in various places as to how to do this, but I haven't seen anything that shows how to build the form and the controller action associated with that form.  Also I'm going to be trying to use check boxes for the most part and I  haven't seen many examples that do that.

Here's a sample of  what I have so far.  :manhattan_served and :brooklyn_served are just 2 examples of attributes.  I hope to have something like 20, where the user can check off maybe 5 or 6 of those attributes at a time.

/app/views/experts/filtered_experts.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag filtered_experts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag(:manhattan_served, "Serves Manhattan") %>
  <%= check_box_tag :manhattan_served, true%>

  <%= label_tag(:brooklyn_served, "Serves Brooklyn") %>
  <%= check_box_tag :brooklyn_served, true%>

<%= submit_tag "Filter", name: nil %> 
<% end %>
```

Here's what I have in my controller

/app/controllers/experts_controller.rb

```
    def filtered_experts
      @experts = Expert.where(params[filtering_params])
    end

private

    def filtering_params
      params.slice(:manhattan_served, :brooklyn_served)
    end
```

Right now, when I submit I just return the full list every time.  In looking at my rails server log, it looks like this is getting passed in to the controller:

```
    Processing by ExpertsController#filtered_experts as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "manhattan_served"=>"true", "brooklyn_served"=>"true"}
```

Any idea why this wouldn't just return to me only experts who serve Brooklyn and Manhattan?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the filtering, so I'm not sure what to suggest as an alternative...

I can tell you though, that the reason you're seeing it return all results is because of:

```
params[filtering_params]
```

Hash.slice in rails returns a copy of the hash with just the specified keys, so your filtering_params() call is returning {:manhattan_served => true, :brooklyn_served => true}.  You're then using this as a hash key when you do:

```
@experts = Expert.where(params[filtering_params])
```

Since that hash lookup obviously fails, it returns nil. If you call .where() with nil, it's like doing:

```
SELECT * from experts WHERE 1=1;
```

You can fix this one case by simply changing that call to:

```
@experts = Expert.where(filtering_params)
```

But I suspect you'll run into other problems later on depending on how many params you're filtering/etc.  I'd recommend looking into named scopes.  You can chain them together to build an AR relationship and it's often how folks solve some of these problems.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Thanks, so I was looking in to doing this with scopes as well.  What I got stuck on was how to pass information from the form_tag in to the controller to invoke the scope.  What should the controller look like?  For example i have     scope :manhattan_served, -> { where(manhattan_served: true) }
    scope :brooklyn_served, -> { where(brooklyn_served: true) } as scopes in my model now.  If a user simply checks the Manhattan box, what should the controller look like so that it only invokes the Manhattan scope, but not the Brooklyn one?

Comment: If you change those scope definitions to something like:

`scope :manhattan_served, -> (manhattan_served) {where("manhattan_served LIKE ?", manhattan_served ||= '%')`

You can then chain them together in your controller:

`Expert.manhattan_served(params[:manhattan_served]).brooklyn_served(params[:brooklyn_served])`

The effect of the ' LIKE %' is to wildcard if you don't provide a value.  So if one of those params evaluates to 'nil' (because you didn't provide it), it will simply wildcard that field and search on the other.  If you specify both params, it will return explicit matches for both.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with the has_scope gem. I wanted to build it from scratch to really understand it, but for what I ultimately want to do I think building from scratch might be a bit too complicated. Thanks for your help